# iFrame doesn't post back with postMessage

Tags: jquery, iframe, modal-dialog

I'm building a modal filled with iFrame content. Inside that modal I have a dropbox upload function. What I try to do is when somebody succesfully uploads an image and click the "close" button that the info is posted back to the original site. Then I can show a nice button with "image uploaded" or something. 
Problem is that i constantly get an error saying `SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified..... window.parent.postMessage('close', url);`

The url for the iFrame:

```
http://www.webshop.com/dropboxupload/?id=1042013-72374&amp;url=http://www.website.com/&amp;place=0#
```

The code:

```
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&amp;]+([^=&amp;]+)=([^&amp;]*)/gi, function(m,key,value){vars[key] = value; }); 
return vars;
}

function close_parent(){ 
    var url = getUrlVars()["url"]; 
    //console.log(url);
    window.parent.postMessage('close', url);
}
```

When I use console.log in the code I get just "htt" without the rest of the url.

The Html for the closing button:

```
<a class="close uploadbutton" onclick="javascript:close_parent();" href="#">Voltooien</a>
```

The code when returning to the original site:

```
 var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
                var eventer = window[eventMethod];
                var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
                var url = window.location.href;

                eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
                  if(e.data == 'close'){
                    up_popover_hide();
                    var urlIframe = $('iframe#upload').attr("src");
                    var indexPlace = getUrlVars(urlIframe )["place"];
                    var idUpload = getUrlVars(urlIframe )["id"];
                    $('.placeholder.index_'+indexPlace+' .upload_'+idUpload).html('File uploaded!');
                  }else{}},false);
```

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong and don't understand why I just get "htt" instead of the full url.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://danheberden.com/share/feec82.png

Comment: @DanHeberden: Ok thx for your answer. What is going wrong then? I can't see why this should not work! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I had this problem and this question is the second link in Google. So I had this problem and I solved it just making sure the string of the url starts with 'http://' or 'https://' if that te case.
And that solved it. 
Hope it helps someone